# Merge array items into one array with three layers based on keys

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have a big array of events that is structured like this from my database:

```
$events = array(
    // Sept 10 2018
    array(
        2018 => array(
            9 => array(
                10 => array(
                    'event01'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    // Sept 20 2018
    array(
        2018 => array(
            9 => array(
                20 => array(
                    'event02'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    // Oct 5 2019
    array(
        2018 => array(
            10 => array(
                5 => array(
                    'event03'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Which I need to be structured like this:

```
$result = array(
    2018 => array(
        // September
        9 => array(
            10 => array(
                'event01'
            ),
            20 => array(
                'event02'
            )
        ),
        // October
        10 => array(
            5 => array(
                'event03'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I'm trying to put it together with `array_key_exists` in three `foreach`s but I haven't done much good progress and not sure if it's the best way to do it. The structure for the initial array is a fixed format, and the data are dynamic.

Help, anyone? Thanks in advance.

Comment: to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Like almost all questions on SO if you show some code you will get a better response from the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3 `foreach` loop to achieve your result;

```
$eventFiltered = [];
foreach ($events as $eventByYear) {
    foreach ($eventByYear as $year => $eventByMonth) {
        foreach ($eventByMonth as $month => $eventByDay) {
            $eventFiltered[$year][$month][key($eventByDay)][] = $eventByDay[key($eventByDay)][0];
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($eventFiltered);
exit;
```

Your output will be;

```
// Output; $eventFiltered

Array
(
    [2018] => Array
        (
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => event01
                        )

                    [20] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => event02
                        )

                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => event03
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you! This allowed me to also filter out together the events on the same day. Life saver 

Comment: Yes; that is I have in my mind that you may be want event on same day also; I also asked same question to @iainn also

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write any loops, just pass all the elements of the array to `array_replace_recursive`:

```
$merged = array_replace_recursive(...$events);
```

This also has the benefit that it'll work an arbitrary number of levels, so if the structure changes in future then the code doesn't have to.

See https://3v4l.org/BP556

Comment: If I am having more than 1 event on same date it will only give last event on that day; what if I want all event?

Comment: Didn't know it can be used like this but yes could be a problem if there is more than one event in a day. Thank you, still!

Comment: @DivyeshPrajapati Not sure I follow, sorry - the output in my example matches what's in the question. If any of the leaf nodes have more than one element, they'll all be present in the result.

Comment: Yeah, it matches the exact o/p but I thought what if more than one event on same day? That's why I asked if it is possible to do with any array function or not.

Comment: @DivyeshPrajapati I still don't understand what you mean. If there is more than one event on the same day, [they'll all be in the result](https://3v4l.org/a07Io). What do you mean *it will only give last event on that day*?

Comment: Your input array is different; look what I mean, https://paiza.io/projects/3G4gPQYEIQU-XOBlKo1QXw